# Azure SQL: can we grant 'execute' permission for stored procedure to API connections in logic app?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azure-sql-server, azure-authentication, azure-logic-app-standard

I want to execute the stored procedures from the logic app.

I have added an SQL connector for it.
but in the 'Procedure name' dropdown, that particular procedure is not visible to me.

do I need to get permission from the admin,
to grant execute permission for the stored procedure for a particular API connection?
or do I have to get permission for any other objects/azure services?

I added permission to the logic app resource group but still, a stored procedure is not visible in the dropdown.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us what type of API connection have you provided?

Comment: @ SwethaKandikonda-MT I am using  SQL Server Authentication API connection

Comment: Can you make sure that your procedures exist in Stored Procedure of your database https://i.imgur.com/bOHxKKD.png

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT Yes. it is present in the database

Comment: In your API connection, you ve specified a connectionstring with username and password ? you should be able to grant this particular user access to the database the same way you would do for any other type of application